# Java (Bukkit) - Wait before executing next line

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently having problems with a plugin. I want to give a player effects for 5 seconds and after the 5 seconds, it should be day. My problem is, that the day command is executing instantly, so it is day, before the effects are over.
Can you help me, that the command for setting the time to 1000 waits 5 seconds before executing?
Help would be appreciated,
Till

```
p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS, 100, 100, true));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW, 100, 100, true));
                    p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 100, -100, true));
                    p.sendMessage("§aGute Nacht!"); //german, dont worry :D
//here should be the delay of 5 seconds
                    Bukkit.getWorld("world").setTime(1000);
```

Comment: You should be using the scheduler (https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming).

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend using the [BukkitRunnable](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html). This class is provided as an easy way to handle scheduling tasks.

```
new BukkitRunnable(
  public void run() {
    Bukkit.getWorld("world").setTime(1000);
  }
).runTaskLater​(yourPluginInstance, delayInTicks);
```

Remember that 20 sever ticks is equal to 1 server second. So `delayInTicks = 5s * 20 = 100`

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `scheduleSyncDelayedTask`
I haven't tested this, but you should be aiming for something like this.

```
myPlugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(myPlugin, new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      Bukkit.getWorld("world").setTime(1000);
  }
}, 100);
```

[scheduleSyncDelayedTask](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#scheduleSyncDelayedTask(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

> Schedules a once off task to occur as soon as possible. This task will
>   be executed by the main server thread.
>
> Parameters:
>
> plugin - Plugin that owns the task
>
> task - Task to be
>   executed
>
> Returns: Task id number (-1 if scheduling failed)

Comment: Hey, sorry if this may sound stupid for you, but I am still a beginner. If I paste your text, the both "myPlugin"'s get marked as "false". What should I write instead of myPlugin?

Comment: You should use the reference of your plugin. You should view the link posted by @[van dench] in your original question to see more examples.

Comment: Remember that 20 sever ticks is equal to 1 server second. 5000 server ticks would be a server time of 250 seconds

Comment: This is a bad answer as the Bukkit Documentation says that the BukkitScheduler is deprecated. Do not provide deprecated code and use the answer Drayke has given! Thanks

Comment: @Scriptblade [BukkitScheduler](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html) I may have misread, but I'm using a `Runnable`, and not a `BukkitRunnable`, and this method isn't marked as deprecated.

Comment: Hey, BukkitScheduler and BukkitRunnable are not the same. You are calling a BukkitScheduler with `getScheduler()`. Methods of the BukkitScheduler are more and more getting deprecated, which means they will be removed in the future. https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html here you can see that more than 50% of the methods are deprecated. As I said before, Drayke has given the right answer.